How to use polymorphism to dynamically create class in Flask with sqlalchemy?
I'm trying to process user input data in a form. Ad is the base class, Housing, ForSale, Job are its child. I want to create the appropriate class based on different input. Currently, I'm using if statement to differentiate different class. Is there a way to dynamically to create the class? And I do get the warning "SAWarning: Flushing object <HousingAd at 0x7c9a1a3765d0> with incompatible polymorphic identity 'Housing'; the object may not refresh and/or load correctly" once I hit submit in the form.
Relevant code are
model.py
class Ad(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)   
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) 
    subcategory_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subcategory.id'), nullable=False)
    Ad_type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    photos = db.relationship('Photo',cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ad',
        "polymorphic_on": Ad_type
    }

class HousingAd(Ad):
    __tablename__ = 'housing_ad'
    rent = db.Column(db.Float)
    rent_period = db.Column(db.Enum('day', 'week', 'month'))    
    type = db.Column(db.Enum('room', 'house', 'homestay', 'vacation', 'other'))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'housing',
    }

class ForSaleAd(Ad):
    __tablename__ = 'for_sale_ad'
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(50))    
    condition = db.Column(db.Enum('new','used','deficiency'))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'for_sale',
    }

class JobAd(Ad):
    __tablename__ = 'job_ad'
    industry = db.Column(db.String(50))
    compensation = db.Column(db.String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'job',
    }
class Photo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    ad_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ad.id'))
    ad_type =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)    
    subcategory = db.relationship('Subcategory')    

class Subcategory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    ad = db.relationship('Ad')

auth.py
@auth.route("/post-ads/<category>/<subcategory>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def post_ad(category,subcategory):
if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.form.get('subject')
        body = request.form.get('body')
        photos =request.files.getlist('photo')
    if category == 'Housing':
        housingAd = HousingAd(subject=subject, body=body, Ad_type=category, user_id=userId, subcategory_id=subcategoryId)
        db.session.add(housingAd)
        db.session.commit()
        ad_id=housingAd.id
    if category == 'For Sale':
        pass
    if category == 'Jobs':
        pass
        
        ad_type = Category.query.filter_by(name=category).first().id
        createPhoto(photos,ad_id,ad_type)
        flash('post ad successfully!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.home'))

def createPhoto(photos,ad_id,ad_type):
    uploads_folder = path.join(getcwd(),Config.UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    if not path.exists(uploads_folder):
        makedirs(uploads_folder)
    if photos:
        for photo in photos:           
            if photo and photo.filename:                    
                photo.save(path.join(uploads_folder, photo.filename))
                new_photo = Photo(filename=photo.filename,ad_id=ad_id,ad_type=ad_type)
                db.session.add(new_photo)
                db.session.commit()
            else:
                flash('No file selected or file is empty.','danger')

I chose "polymorphic_on": Ad_type, and use ad_type to differentiate the kind of Ad, and the ad_id to associate photo with an ad. I can get all the user input and the photos uploaded by user. But the Ad is not created and stored in database.
